# Should I use cookies, sessions, or user accounts?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, identification

I'm trying to develop a website for reviewing TV series, and I want to limit the rating for a show to one rating per user, and I kind of have no idea where to start, since I'm very new to web development. I'm using Vue.js on the front-end; Node.js with Express on the back-end.

From what I understand, cookies should not be suitable for this purpose since they can be deleted by the user, am I right?
I've also read about sessions and how they are stored on the server rather than the browser (but I also don't know what sessions are or how to implement them).
There's also the user registration system possibility. So, which one of these methods should I use for this purpose?
If you could also tell me about where to start (direct me to tutorials, code snippets, ..) I would be really grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like said by Mr. Anonymous, you need **User Accounts**. However you could achieve this using in your case, for example, [expressjs/session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to create sessions and [passport.js](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) for the user authentication part.

[Here](https://medium.com/of-all-things-tech-progress/starting-with-authentication-a-tutorial-with-node-js-and-mongodb-25d524ca0359) there is a simple tutorial using these two libraries and mongo-db for saving user data.

If you want implement your own session library (**only for learning purpose**), you can follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102391/creating-session-without-external-libraries) advices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use all 3 and if your new to web development this will take you some time to get right. You will need user registration, a login system, and when users log in you will create sessions ( which internally use cookies) and if you want them to login with "remember me" you need to explicitly use cookies.

**Sessions**

This is how express/your-web-app will remember that a user is logged in. Under the hood its using cookies on the users machine that map to ids stored in memory on your server. Without sessions and cookies your users will have to log in on every page....You don't have to worry about how sessions use cookies yourself. There is express middleware libraries that handle this for you so you just interact with sessions like any other object, but its good to know that sessions internally use cookies. You can find lots of articles expanding on this.

**Cookies**

You will explicitly have to create cookies if you want to give your users the "Remember Me" login option. If you don't care about that then you can force them to log in and then create a session so they wont have to log in again for 20 mins or however long you want.

**User Accounts**

User accounts are records in a database that uniquely identify each user. The sessions and cookies all point back to this. That is where your store your users information such as their username, email, and whether or not they have already voted on a TV series. When a user logs in you lookup their identity in your database and if you find one you then create a session so they don't have log in again as they navigate your site for a set amount of time.

**Recommendation**

Start small. Forget about Vue.js for now and use plain HTML until you understand these basic components sessions, cookies, and how to build a login and registration page. If, and I respectfully mean if, you get that working then you can work on making it look pretty and fancy in the front using Vue.js.